# Weather Icons Broken OpenWeather Gnome Extension

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

I can't seem to fix this issue.  Using the OpenWeather Gnome extension in ubuntu 19.04 the weather icons are broken with a exclamation mark on them.  I've tried removing and re-adding the extension even moved to darksky.  Nothing seems to fix them.  I swear they used to work but I'm starting to question it.  Any idea how to fix?

[image]

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. One year later and nothing change!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and the Adwaita (default) icon set.

I could fix it by selecting another icon set like Paper.

[image: icons screenshot]

You can switch the icon set with [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks). Install that using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the icon set to Adwaita++, you can download it [here](https://github.com/Bonandry/adwaita-plus#installing-the-stable-version-with-cli). They have install instructions.